# Find and replace not working in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch script with find and replace option but the batch script doesn't do anything instead just show the blinking cursor and gets stuck there.

Here's the coding I'm using:

```
setlocal
set this=abhinav2

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('^<test\abc.new findstr /n "^"') do ('
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:*:=!"
    if not "!line!"=="!line:<xyz>mnishamk<abc>" set "line=<xyz>%this%<abc>"
    (echo(!line!)>>test\new.abc
    endlocal
)
)
```

I can't simply replace `mnishamk` with `abhinav2` as there are lots of names with `mnishamk` present in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax issue, see `set /?` for help and try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line=<xyz>mnishamk<abc>"
set "this=abhinav2"

if not "!line!"=="!line:<xyz>mnishamk<abc>=!" set "line=<xyz>%this%<abc>"
echo !line!
```

output is:

```
<xyz>abhinav2<abc>
```

And this also works:

```
set "line=!line:<xyz>mnishamk<abc>=<xyz>%this%<abc>!"
```

Comment: It says: 
<xyz>abhinav2<abc>
system can't find the file specified.     BTW the file I want to edit is abc.new in a folder named test. `i'm really sorry but im a newbie to batch.

Comment: The last line of your `abc.new` file **must** end with `CR/LF`, otherwise batch findstr bricks!

Comment: Yes it does end but still :(

Comment: So use `find`, not `findstr`.

Comment: Now just opens and closes  :(

Comment: I can't understand this :( and would recommend: make a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO off
setlocal
DEL \test\new.abc /F /Q
set this=abhinav2

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('^<\test\abc.new findstr /n "^"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:*:=!"
    if not "!line!"=="!line:<xyz>mnishamk<abc>=!" set "line=!line:<xyz>mnishamk<abc>=<xyz>%this%<abc>!"
    echo(!line!>>\test\new.abc
    endlocal
)

FC \test\abc.new \test\new.abc
```

This worked for me...

Comment: It says system ccan't find the file specified :(

Comment: Try changing `\test` throughout to `test`. The file location that you have specified is relative to your current directory; if you move away from your current directory, `test\new.abc` will be meaningless. I've merely used fully-defined or "absolute" paths.